# Цвет гистограммы Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Как изменить цвет гистограммы при переходе через 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
s = np.random.normal(0, 100, 10000)
n, bins, patches= plt.hist(x=s, bins='auto', color='orange')
for bn, pt in zip(bins, patches):
    if bn<=0:
        pt.set_facecolor("b")
```

Аналогично можно раскрасить хоть каждый бин в отдельности.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
colors = ['blue' if i > 0 else 'red' for i in y]
ax.bar(x, y, color=colors)
```